# How to convert string with special character as array php

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, key-value

I have a string like this below.

```
"|dm:12|em:.25|fm:10|wm:85|de:143|qty:1"
```

How to convert it as key-value pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code

```
foreach(array_filter(explode("|", "|dm:12|em:.25|fm:10|wm:85|de:143|qty:1")) as $ListItem){
    $Item = explode(":", $ListItem);
    $KVP[$Item[0]] = isset($Item[1]) ? $Item[1] : null;
}

var_dump($KVP);
```

Output

```
array(6) {
  'dm' =>
  string(2) "12"
  'em' =>
  string(3) ".25"
  'fm' =>
  string(2) "10"
  'wm' =>
  string(2) "85"
  'de' =>
  string(3) "143"
  'qty' =>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: This won't output a key/value pair.

Comment: @cOle2 Thanks mate, made the adjustments

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm bored.  Just replace the `|` with `&` and `:` with `=` to get a query string to parse into an array:

```
parse_str(str_replace(['|', ':'], ['&', '='], $string), $result);
```

Or you can capture the pieces that you want and combine them:

```
preg_match_all('/\|([^:]+):([^|]+)/', $string, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

- Match a `|`
- `([^:]+)` Match and capture anything NOT `:`
- Match `:`
- `([^|]+)` Match and capture anything NOT `|`

Comment: Watch out if the result might convert the Value in the name of URL decoding, in case if you have some special character for Value data.